# Dynamo DB -- ClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/ClientConfigurationFactory

Tags: java, maven, amazon-dynamodb

I have a dependency od dynamo DB in my pom.xml as

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-dynamodb</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.70</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

It was working fine till now but suddenly it started to show the below error

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/amazonaws/ClientConfigurationFactory
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:2558) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:859) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1302) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.38]
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1167) ~[catalina.jar:8.0.38]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBClient.(AmazonDynamoDBClient.java:230) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.11.70.jar:na]
    at com.medlife.dynamoDb.client.DynamoDbStarter.init(DynamoDbStarter.java:56) ~[dynamoDb-services-1.0.54.jar:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_111]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_111]

Does somebody knows the solution to this

Comment: Try updating your maven project. Right Click on your project -> Maven -> Update. See if it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class `com/amazonaws/ClientConfigurationFactory` is part of AWS SDK core module.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
    <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.70</version>
</dependency>
```

The above dependency (aws-java-sdk-core) is included on `aws-java-sdk-dynamodb`.

Please check whether the maven local repository has the core module. Otherwise, you can just run the `mvn clean install` command to get the dependencies from remote repository.

**Local repository path:-**

```
C:\Users\userid\.m2\repository\com\amazonaws\aws-java-sdk-core\1.11.70
```

Comment: Could you please accept the answer if it was helpful?